# Async methods in c#: Continuation point

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mono, async-await

I have the following code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace asynctest {
    class Program {
        public static void Main (string[] args) {
            var program = new Program ();
            program.run ();
        }

        public Program () {
        }

        public void run () {
            asynctest ();
            Console.WriteLine ("Sync");
            while (true) {
            }
        }

        public async Task asynctest () {
            await Task.Delay (100);
            Console.WriteLine ("Async");
        }
    }
}
```

When starting this program i would expect the output to be just "Sync", because the asynctest-method is never continued in my code.

Instead it outputs both "Sync" and "Async".

My question is now where exactly the program switches from the run method to the asynctest method to print the "Async" line. From my previous experiences with coroutines this should not happen.

Comment: It will never switch from `run` to `asynctest`. Another thread executes the code after `Task.Delay`(i.e continuation). In this case `ThreadPool` thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks initiated from Console programs run on the thread pool by default, so your program starts running on thread A. Your `asynctest` method gets called and as soon as it encounters `await Task.Delay (100);` it returns and then continues to write out the `Sync` string. Then thread A blocks on the `while` loop.

The compiler builds a state machine out of the `asynctest` method, which upon the finish of `Task.Delay(100)` resumes execution on  thread pool thread B and prints `Async`. Then thread B terminates. Thread A remains stuck on the `while` loop.

If you called this from a UI thread you would get a deadlock as `await` will try to execute the remainder of the `asynctest` method on the UI thread, which in turn is blocked in the `while(true)` loop.

Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), it explains a bit more about `async` and `await` best practices.

Comment: Why is a new thread used (B) and execution not scheduled on thread A?  Is that because it is busy doing its "while looping"?

Comment: When you call `await` on an a thread pool `SynchrinizationContext`, the continuation can be executed on any thread from the thread pool. i guess if thread A was available, the implementation can choose to schedule the remainder of the method there or any of the other available threads. I think this is implementation detail. There are [ways] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) to execute on exactly the same thread, but you will get a deadlock

Comment: This sounds reasonable, so i am marking this as correct, until someone proves it wrong. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: “Console programs run on the thread pool” No, they don't. You can verify that by accessing `Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread` from `Main()`: it returns `false`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I'll fix that up. Does it use a dedicated thread for the console?